# Checking for load testing in nodejs , doesn't save any entry

Tags: node.js

I am testing for load testing. 
I am using [faker](https://www.npmjs.org/package/faker) Package also using [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request)

I  want to check for signup

fronend url for signup is

**localhost/test/signup.com**
and going to **localhost:8081/register**
like this

> ```
>    $.ajax({
>                 type: "POST",
>                 url: commonpath+'register',
>                 dataType: "JSON",
>                 data: {first_name:firstname,last_name:lastname, user_name:username,email:eamilid,password:password},
>                 async: true,
>                 success: function(data) {
> ```

and so on....

i create a new file for testing

here is code

```
exports.fakedata = function(req, res) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
for (var i=0; i < number_of_signups; i++) {
  identities.push({
    first_name: faker.name.firstName(),
    last_name: faker.name.lastName(),
    user_name :  "hitu"+faker.internet.email(),
    email: "hitu"+faker.internet.email(),
    password: faker.internet.password()
  });

  }
        async.each(identities, submit, function(err,res) {
                console.log("each function");
                  if(err) throw err;
                    console.log('done...');
                        process.exit();
        });


//console.log(JSON.stringify(identities));      


};
function submit(identity, callback) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(identity));
firstname="hello"; / jsut tio chck */
lastname= "hhf";//identity[0].last_name;
username= "dffflffl";//identity.user_name;
email="email@hitemai.com"//identity.email;
password= "dddd";//identity.password;

  var opts = {
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/register',
    method: 'POST',
     data: {first_name:firstname,last_name:lastname, user_name:username,email:email,password:password},
  };

  request(opts, function(err, connection, body) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("there is an error " +err);
        return callback(err);
        }else {
            console.log("pls check db entry ");
                callback();
    }
  });
}
```

at console when i am checking  message is showing please check db entry .. but there is no entry.

Can anybody tell me response pls, how to do this

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that the signup handler works as expected?

Comment: yes.. singup is working fine

Comment: try capturing the POST data that the signup handler gets, to see if you actually get what you are sending it

Comment: I am not sure.  my handler is working here..

Comment: I am not getting data on singup function

Comment: instead of putting your data in the `data` parameter, trying using the `body` parameter, also set `json` to `true` in the request

Comment: Error: Error: Argument error, options.body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65495/discussion-between-hayko-koryun-and-hitu-bansal).